# Can I set conditional formatting based on cell which is located in same file but on other worksheet in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two google worksheet one named sample1 and another sample2. I have value 2 in A1 of sample1, now can I check if sample2 A1 is equal to A1 of sample2 which should also be 2, if false, set color to red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use values from another page of the spreadsheet, in a custom conditional formatting function, use the function:

[INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

Additional Reference: [Role of Indirect Function in Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/role-of-indirect-function-in-conditional-formatting-in-google-sheets/)